# How to create form that takes data from API?

Tags: javascript, api

So I want to create web app that takes data from API. And it should be just form and under that form data will show up not as JSON, but normal text. Sketch here:
HTML

```
<div><form><input id="form" type="text" placeholder="search" size="20" /></form></div>
<div id="data"><h2>First name: John</h2>
<h2>Last name: Doe</h2>
<h2>Country: Canada</h2>
<h4>*not as JSON</h4></div>
```

CSS

```
#form {
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 50px;
}
#data {
  background-color: green;
  width: 620px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

I guess that it's a lot of javascript to do, but I don't even know how to start with this.

Comment: You can use AJAX for this which is defined in jQuery plugin.

Comment: Can you say what api you want to consume?

Comment: It is GitHub API.